# Cannot get ValueFilter from hbase without error in the shell

Tags: shell, filter

I am new to Htable and there is something I would like to do. I'm looking for a value in the table "test". I found that I have to use the Filter system with ValueFilter function.
Here are the commands that I have tested so far:

`scan 'test',{FILTER=>"ValueFilter(CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL,Bytes.toBytes('test'))"}`

`scan 'test',{FILTER=>"ValueFilter(CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL,'test')"}`

But I see this error every time :

`ERROR: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Incorrect filter string ValueFilter(CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL,Bytes.toBytes('test')`

What is wrong with my filter? ( the Prefix filters works well )

This one didn't worked either: 
[doing a ValueFilter or a ColumnFilter on hbase shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12634321/doing-a-valuefilter-or-a-columnfilter-on-hbase-shell)