# How to get a column value based on criteria like where clause in Hbase shell

Tags: hbase

I am new to Hbase.

I have a scenario where I need to pull a filename based on the status and current date.

So I have created 3 columns; `filename`, `status` and `date` in the `Hbase` table.

How can I get the filename based on the condition that the `status=true` and date is today?

This query needs to be executed on the Hbase shell.

Comment: Have a look at the answers of the following questions. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12634321/doing-a-valuefilter-or-a-columnfilter-on-hbase-shell 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013197/scan-htable-rows-for-specific-column-value-using-hbase-shell

Comment: Thanks ,I have gone through the links .But I haven't got the solution yet. just to rephrase my question, say i have 3 coiumns in my table. i need to get the first column corresponding to a condition which is applied on 2nd column and 3rd columns. The sql equivalent of this would be    select first column from table where (2nd column =x  and 3rd column=y).    i need this implemented in the hbase shell.

Comment: My bad, misread the question. I'll give it a shot at the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Achieving this in a concise way is difficult. But here is what I did.
`hbase shell` is a `JRuby` shell, which enables us to do the following example.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.SingleColumnValueFilter
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.CompareFilter
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.SubstringComparator
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.FilterList

filter1 = SingleColumnValueFilter.new(Bytes.toBytes('cf'), Bytes.toBytes('qualifier'), CompareFilter::CompareOp.valueOf('EQUAL'), SubstringComparator.new('valueToSearch'));
filter2 = SingleColumnValueFilter.new(Bytes.toBytes('cf'), Bytes.toBytes('qualifier2'), CompareFilter::CompareOp.valueOf('EQUAL'), SubstringComparator.new('valueToSearch2'));

filterList = FilterList.new([filter1, filter2]);

scan 'table', {FILTER =>  filterList}
```

You could import any other `Filters`, `Comparator`, `Java` objects etc

I have used `SubstringComparator` for testing.
In your case it should be `BinaryComparator` (Probably better performance wise as well).

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256100/scan-with-filter-using-hbase-shell) question if you want to read more about a similar hack.

Hope it helps.