# Hbase multiple ValueFilter's to filter multiple columns of the same row

Tags: hbase

I would like to achieve something like this SQL query using the HBase API

```
SELECT * FROM customer_table WHERE firstname = "Joe" AND lastname = "Bloggs" AND email = "joe@blah.com"
```

HBase Table:

```
1                column=p:firstname, timestamp=<t>, value=Joe                                                                         
1                column=p:lastname, timestamp=<t>, value=Bloggs                                                                            
1                column=p:email, timestamp=<t>, value=joe@blah.com                                                                            
2                column=p:firstname, timestamp=<t>, value=Joe                                                                         
2                column=p:lastname, timestamp=<t>, value=Bloggs                                                                            
2                column=p:email, timestamp=<t>, value=joe@blah.com
3                column=p:firstname, timestamp=<t>, value=Joe                                                                         
3                column=p:lastname, timestamp=<t>, value=Bloggs                                                                            
3                column=p:email, timestamp=<t>, value=joe@blah.com
```

Currently I have this:

```
val filters = Array("Joe", "Bloggs", "joe@blah.com")

// AND operator
val filterList = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL) 

filters.foreach(f => {
  filterList.addFilter(new ValueFilter(CompareOp.EQUAL, new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes(f))))
})

val scan = new Scan().setFilter(filterList)
val resultScanner = table.getScanner(scan)
```

But, this returns no results.  I would expect it to return all 3 rows.  Is there another filter/function to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31580382/3213111) answer helped me.  I needed to use a `SingleColumnValueFilter` instead of the `ValueFilter`, because it is an AND operation, you need to create a column value filter for each field you need to filter on, which `SingleColumnValueFilter` does nicely.

```
val filterMap = Map("firstname" -> "Joe", "lastname" -> "Bloggs", "email" -> "joe@blah.com")

// AND operator
val filterList = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL) 

filterMap.foreach(kv => {
  filterList.addFilter(new SingleColumnValueFilter
    (
      Bytes.toBytes(columnFamily),
      Bytes.toBytes(kv._1),
      CompareOp.EQUAL,
      new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes(kv._2))
    )
  )
})

val scan = new Scan().setFilter(filterList)
val resultScanner = table.getScanner(scan)
```

This returns the 3 rows as expected.